# Dynamic web part sourced from another web part.

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer

We have a webpart (webpartA) which is updated manually, and we have another webpart (webpartB).

What I want to have is, when webpartA is updated, I want webpartB to be updated automatically. Is there a way to do this without using sharepoint designer.

Comment: Are these custom webparts or OOTB SharePoint webparts like Content Editor? 
If they are custom webparts than you can fetch the data from a common source and they would update automatically once you update the data.

Can you describe the exact scenario to understand this better,
Jomit

Answer (score 1):

Using connected webpart in sharepoint you can do it

see this link. It may help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx